# How to overcome underflow when obtaining a vector in simplex?

Tags: precision

I'm normalizing a vector to make its sum 1 so that the vector will be used for a parameter in multinomial distribution.

Here's a toy example. Let `x` be a vector with positive values and `sigma` is very small positive number. When I run this R code, `y` is all zero due to underflow, so is its sum.

```
x <- rep(1, 10)
sigma <- 1e-3
y <- exp(-x/sigma) # 0's
prob <- y / sum(y) # NaNs
```

Do you have any idea to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the log_sum_exp function as

```
log_sum_exp <- function(x) {
  m <- max(x)
  return(m + log(sum(exp(x - m))))
}
```

and then `prob <- exp(y - log_sum_exp(y))` is the "softmax" of `y`.